# Limit abusable privileges to non-anonymous users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Cyberbullying, as research shows, is strongly facilitated by anonymity. To limit abuse of privileges, I suggest that certain privileges – such as single-handedly marking questions as duplicate – should be reserved for those users that have the courage to put a face and name to their actions.

I would also expect that moderators and company employees active on a professional site do not hide behind pseudonyms.

Comment: Marking a question as a duplicate already produces a comment on the question and once closed the users who close voted are shown. Doesn't that make them non-anonymous?

Comment: Folks are free to choose whatever level of anonymity they like. However, more concerning is the subtle association you've made with "cyberbullying" and "closing a question as a duplicate [by a mod or gold badge holder]" (plus, a user's real name being revealed would probably not impact their perception of whether or not a question was a duplicate). Is there a specific question you have an issue with? You can also make a case in a comment or an edit, and vote to reopen.

Comment: @JasonC The first sentence of your comment bears no relation to my question. I did not propose to limit anonymity.

Comment: @what Then I'm voting to close this as unclear, as *"... strongly facilitated by anonymity ... should be reserved for those users that have the courage to put a face and name to their actions ...  do not hide behind pseudonyms"* can be interpreted no other way, so I'm not entirely sure what you mean, then. If you meant something else, consider editing. Is there a specific post you have an issue with?

Comment: @rene A username such as "rene" is anonymous, as it does not give your true identity away.

Comment: So is *what* then. If you're so into this non-anonymity: What is your real identity?

Comment: @JasonC I did not propose to limit anonymity, but to limit the rights of anonymous users, which is not the same. You can walk the street without telling anyone your name (you have the right to remain anonymous), but once you want to drive a car or vote, you have to show your passport (you have to give up anonymity for certain privileges).

Comment: @what You're being more than a bit weaselly here.

Comment: @rene I don't want to disclose my identity, but I propose that I should not be given the right to mark questions as duplicate, because hidden behind my pseudonym, and without anyone being able to attribute my behavior to my non-stackexchange professional self, I am strongly inclined to abuse my power (and I have).

Comment: @JasonC How so?

Comment: Let's assume for a moment that SE implements what you propose. How do you envision that users have their true identity verified? Does Joel need to visit everyone? Does Stack Overflow needs to open offices around the world? Do we all need to send in our passport or id-cards? And even if we forget these practicalities, would that change much as the users would still live up to the general goal of the site and moderate it as such. Or do you really think users from one part of the world would  send out a hitman to kick me in the balls and that outlook should make me hold back on close voting?

Comment: @rene Users who chose to use the site non-anonymously could use a procedure such as [Postident](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postident) to create a verified email account such as [De-Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-Mail) to sign up. A verified email address can be of use to individuals in other contexts (e.g. doing your taxes online), so creating such an account might not be such an obstacle. The Postident procedure is available to all online service providers in Germany, and SE could instigate such a service internationally. Verifiability of identity is a need for many online partners

Comment: And then SE has a verified identity, fine. What are they going to do with it then? Up until now they were very protective about PII. Or are you now in a state of mind that you want to pay me a visit?

Comment: @rene not enough. Also must validate identity by eye and finger scanner (both, as attacker can take out one of these) before being able to do any action that might abuse or offend anyone. (aka any action.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this asks for something which is totally and utterly absurd.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44301043/616460) the question that prompted this?

Comment: So how do you prevent the *opposite* from occurring here? Highly-privileged users put their names in their profiles and then people who don't like their actions go and troll/bully them elsewhere on the Internet. How is that fair? You're not gonna like this, but we actually had such a huge problem with users harassing our diamond moderators outside the network after suspensions that we had to make mod messages anonymous and hide their names in them. So, no, we're not going the way you suggest. That would only cause more problems.

Comment: @animuson If the suspended users had not been anonymous when they registered (and legal consequences would have been possible), they wouldn't have dared to harass anyone – and wouldn't probably have misbehaved in the first place.

Comment: @what That's an absolutely terrible argument on a lot of fronts. You're only asking about anonymity of users with privileges, but that comment suggests anonymity would not exist at all on the site to prevent users engaging in misbehavior like this. But some users would still engage and *do engage* in this behavior without anonymity. We've handled plenty of users who use real names who do some pretty atrocious things. As well, when you're harassing a user off-site based on something they did on-site, you don't need to reveal your identity wherever you're doing the harassing.

Comment: By the way, the day I would have to create a [De-Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-Mail#Criticism) account to participate would be the day I'd leave.

Answer (score 15):

> Cyberbullying, as research shows, is strongly facilitated by anonymity

Citation needed.

> To limit abuse of privileges, I suggest that certain privileges – such as single-handedly marking questions as duplicate – should be reserved for those users that have the courage to put a face and name to their actions.

You either need to be a moderator, or to hold a gold badge in a tag. Both of these are non trivial. Amusingly, it would be easier to find me online by my handle than my real name. Also examples of such abuses would be nice,

> I would also expect that moderators and company employees active on a professional site do not hide behind pseudonyms.

I've put my name in a nomination when I stood for election. No one is likely to have remembered it.

On the other hand, "Journeyman Geek" is a name that has a certain amount of recognition here (good or bad!), and I try my best to make sure most of my recognition is the positive sort.

I also feel that you've forgotten there's a reasonable set of check and balances here against abuse. *Minimally* we can ask to have something reopened on per site metas, or flag a moderator.

If it's a regular user, a moderator can talk to them. If it's a moderator, a CM. CMs essentially are the folks who *run* everything on behalf of SE, and well, if we can't trust them to do their jobs, who can we trust?

I'd also add that a lot of people do *good* things anonymously as well. In addition, you're going to need a... frankly unnecessary amount of private information to enforce a *realistic* level of verification on a real name, and whether it's really someone's name.

Even with a lasso of truth, you may get [something unexpected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj7VW.png)

I'm not convinced making me use my real name would make me use my powers any more or less responsibly, and would just result in an *awful* lot of J Smiths.

Comment: You must have detached yourself from reality that you need a [citation](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&q=anonymity+cyberbullying) for that. And I would never say that to your face or write it under my real name, where a colleague or neighbor (who love to google me) would find it. Which is an example, as you asked for, for how I use my anonymity to be rude and offensive.

Comment: If you're going to quote research, you really need to be much more specific. And in this case *how* closures and uses of these privileges equate to cyberbullying. Most cyberbullying is being mean to people, and most of us takes a dim view of that

Comment: More specific than the numerous quotes you can read if you follow that link?!? Does the following quote help?: "the relation between anonymity and cyberbullying attitudes was significant for both 18–26 year olds (B = 0.43, 95% CI: .002 to .87) and 27–35 year olds (B = 0.66, 95% CI: .34 to .95)" (Barlett, C. P., & Chamberlin, K. (2017). Examining cyberbullying across the lifespan. Computers in Human Behavior, 71, 444-449.)

Comment: You should include this and how it is relevant in your question

Comment: lol, no I shouldn't. I'm cooking lunch and have requested for my account to be deleted (and it is now "scheduled to be deleted in 19 hours", so you can have fun with this proposal without me. Bye.

Comment: @what I don't understand. Why start a discussion when you already decided to leave?

Comment: +1 for the picture. You could also use [this one](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-oA1LscQff3I/VL5rnC-EOMI/AAAAAAAADbI/ljP6JG_Kenc/s1600/Lex-Luthor-is-having-a-bad-day.jpg).

Comment: @ModusTollens It is my parting gift.

Comment: @what All right... it's just so unnecessary. It's like walkting into a room, shouting a complaint and then leaving. That's not only a waste of our time, but of yours as well.